# Flutter - iOS devices not sleeping

Tags: ios, flutter, sleep, display, auto-lock

On iOS our app does not let the device sleep - or Auto-Lock as Apple calls it.

All Android devices sleep fine, no problems.

Our previous native apps (coded in Swift & Obj-C) always sleep on the same iOS devices, which suggests its not the devices at fault.

We have no background threads, services, or listeners that might keep the device awake - it's a standalone casual game.

We've tried these without success:
- removing the device from power supply
- full release build directly from XCode, rather than a debug version directly from Studio
- use a Wakelock library + force wakelock off

And the final irritation, it's consistent to an individual device (as in the same device will always stay on), but it's not consistent across a range of devices / OS levels:
- iPhone 5 10.3        no sleep
- iPhone 8 13.3        sleeps
- iPad 2nd Gen 10.3    sleeps
- iPad 6th Gen 13.3    no sleep

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting a similar issue.

Comment: Hello MattChris, we never found the reason, but they work now they're fully signed and in the App Store. I can't imagine full signing could have made a difference, but stranger things have happened. I recommend releasing to a limited audience / internally, and then re-check.

Comment: I'm having similar issue with my app, nothing special I'm doing, it jsut a simple utility App. Not sure why it keep up, not sleep :(